# Sql Server 2000 create scheduled job to run stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, job-scheduling

Have a client that is using sql server 2000. I know tsql. I need to create a scheduled job that runs a script to create a report from and/or insert data into a seperate table. How do i setup a job to run a sql script? Can anyone point me to a guide on creating reports from these jobs. Thanks. Do i need to create dts packages?

Answer (score 0):

> Open SQL Server Enterprise Manager. Expand the Management node. 
>   Right Click Job from the Sub Nodes and Select New Job from the context
>   Menu.

You can use [THIS](http://mudassarkhan.wordpress.com/2009/01/13/job-schedular-sql-server-2000/) to create the jobs.

Answer (score 0):

check out for [Sql Server 2000](http://www.quackit.com/sql_server/tutorial/sql_server_agent_jobs.cfm) for creating the scheduled jobs

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add the full tree path in SQL Server Enterprise manager. Jobs are nested under the SQL Server Agent node in SQL Server Enterprise manager.

- Open SQL Server Enterprise Manager
- Expand Microsoft Sql Servers
- Expand SQL Server Group
- Expand Local
- Expand Management
- Expand Sql Server Agent